# No line found error while executing the below code(Scanner)

Tags: java

I am getting the error as 'No line found' while executing the below code.Please let me know where i went wrong. Here i am trying to get the name of the user who failed to login more than 5 times.

```
int count = 0;
  if(driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div/form/div/div/span")).size()==1) {

      count++;
      if(count>=5)
      System.out.println(user);  

      Scanner scanner_user1, scanner_pass1;
      ChromeOptions options1 = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("start-maximized");
      options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
      options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
      WebDriver driver1 =  new ChromeDriver(options1);
      driver1.get("https://jamesweb.colanonline.net/");
      driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      scanner_user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your Email or Phone2 : "); 
      String user1 = scanner_user1.nextLine();
      driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"EmailId\"]")).sendKeys(user1);
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      scanner_pass1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your Password2 : ");
      String pass1 = scanner_pass1.nextLine();
      System.out.println("after input : ");
      driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]")).sendKeys(pass1);
      scanner_user1.close();
      scanner_pass1.close();

      driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnLogin\"]")).click();
      }

  else {

      System.out.println("Login Passed"); 
  }
```

}

**I got the following error while executing the code**

```
Enter your Email or Phone2 : 
FAILED: Login
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Selenium. You should rewrite this to an [mcve] to isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is no nextLine for the scanner to read.
Try to put

```
while(!scanner.hasNextLine()){}
```

before the nextLine- Statement

Edit: I tried using the scanner on my own programm, it waits for a new line by itself, so the code above is useless in that case.

Why do you have 2 scanners on system.in?

Edit2: If you can't get the scanner to work, you might want to switch to `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` to poll the user input.

Comment: I tried using BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) and this resolved my error